# Find last inserted id while execute multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm executing multiple queries using [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). I tried many things but can't find last inserted ID.

```
$fetchbasic = mysqli_fetch_array($resCheckres);
$cpyname = $fetchbasic['name'].'(copy)';

$query1 = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM name_webinfo WHERE resume_id = ".$resume_id.";
    UPDATE tmptable_1 SET resume_id = NULL , name = '".$cpyname."';
    INSERT INTO name_webinfo SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;";

$resCheckres = mysqli_multi_query($link,$query1);
```

I need the last inserted ID for this query: `INSERT INTO name_webinfo SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;`

Comment: Can your please clearly explain your problem

Comment: i need lastinsertid for this query  "INSERT INTO name_webinfo SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;"

Comment: `SELECT MAX(ID) from tmptable_1` use this bro if it is work please tell me

Comment: Can't tamptable is deleted in next query and max(id) would be conflict problem if some one insert another row

Comment: you are asking last insert id right...?

Comment: yes i need it i am running multi query again base on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working for me it gives you id array

```
do {
    $ids[] = $link->insert_id;
     $link->next_result();
 } while($link->more_results());
 print_r(ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (put select last_insert_id after insert statement):

```
$fetchbasic = mysqli_fetch_array($resCheckres);
$cpyname = $fetchbasic['name'].'(copy)';

    $query1 = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable_1 SELECT * FROM name_webinfo WHERE resume_id = ".$resume_id.";
        UPDATE tmptable_1 SET resume_id = NULL , name = '".$cpyname."';
        INSERT INTO name_webinfo SELECT * FROM tmptable_1;
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable_1;";


    $resCheckres = mysqli_multi_query($link,$query1);
    do {
        if ($result = $link->store_result()) {
           while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
           echo ($row);
           }
        }
    } while ($link->next_result());
```